# Use custom login screen with phpCas

Tags: php, cas, phpcas

I have implemented a basic cas authentication system that authenticates with the cas server via a custom login screen, but now I would like to use a well tested package for this. So wanted to know if there is a way for using phpcas with custom login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching packagist should help, pulling the dependency with composer is also recommended. The only phpCAS library I have used is:

> https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS

This is maintained and supports PHP 5.0+. You can install this dependency with composer, using the following command:

```
composer.phar require jasig/phpca
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but ended up implementing my own way of doing it.